# Import excel to database add date now

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, import-from-excel

I have a working code of importing excel to database in mvc. In these i have a date column which leaves blank after the import. What i want is to insert the date now upon import.

This is my code as of now:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadCsv(HttpPostedFileBase attachmentcsv, Device device)
{
    CsvFileDescription csvFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ',',
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
    };
    CsvContext csvContext = new CsvContext();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(attachmentcsv.InputStream);
    IEnumerable<Device> list = csvContext.Read<Device>(streamReader, csvFileDescription);
    db.Devices.AddRange(list);
    // code for insert Date now on my date column because it leaves blank
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Devices");
}
```

Comment: you have a date colunm and value when u upload date become empty???

Comment: i have  date column in my database but not in the column of my excel file. What i want is to automatically fill the date column in database with date now on all the imported data. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your database property name is UploadDateTime in device class.

```
List<Device> list = csvContext.Read<Device>(streamReader, csvFileDescription).ToList();

//Use below line of code to assign datetime to all object in list then add and save.
list.ForEach(x=> x.UploadDateTime = DateTime.Now);

db.Devices.AddRange(list);
// code for insert Date now on my date column because it leaves blank
db.SaveChanges();
```

**EDIT**

if `list.ForEach` doesn't work then you can use like this

```
//or u can use foreach like below 
foreach ( var item in list)
{
    item.UploadDateTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: It says that IEnumerable<Device> does not contain a definition ForEach :(

Comment: i changed it to list.ToList().ForEach(i => i.dateAdded =DateTime.Now); but still the date column is empty

Comment: Just use `List<Device> list = ` and try again